# Set image encoding default to PNG in QGIS WMS connections

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wms, image-encoding

Some WMS connections in QGIS offer a variety of image encodings and sometimes from am list [PNG, PNG8, JPEG, GIF, TIFF, SVG] JPEG ist selected per default, like shown below, sometimes PNG is selected per default.

**Note** that the default is selected any time one connects to the WMS an cannot be overridden by selecting another option.

**Example #1: default JPEG**

[image]

**Example #2:default PNG**

[image]

The default image encoding seems not defined in the WMS' capabilities, nor am I able to define it when adding a WMS connection manually or via PyQGIS like

```
wms = {'Digitales Orthophoto 80cm (LDBV)':[('', '', ''),(7, False, False, False, False, '', False, 'https://geoservices.bayern.de/wms/v2/ogc_dop80_oa.cgi')]}
set = QgsSettings()
set.beginGroup('qgis/connections-wms')
wms_exist = set.childGroups()
set.endGroup()
wms_cons = wms.keys()
for w in wms_cons:
    if not w in wms_exist:
        auth, params = wms[w]
        authid, user, pwd = auth
        dpi, iaxis, igfi, igmu, invaxis, ref, smooth, url = params
        wms_auth_path = 'qgis/WMS/{0}/'.format(w)
        set.setValue(wms_auth_path + 'authcfg', auth)
        set.setValue(wms_auth_path + 'password', pwd)
        set.setValue(wms_auth_path + 'username', user)
        wms_conf_path = 'qgis/connections-wms/{0}/'.format(w)
        set.setValue(wms_conf_path + 'dpiMode', dpi)
        set.setValue(wms_conf_path + 'ignoreAxisOrientation', iaxis)
        set.setValue(wms_conf_path + 'ignoreGetFeatureInfoURI', igfi)
        set.setValue(wms_conf_path + 'ignoreGetMapURI', igmu)
        set.setValue(wms_conf_path + 'invertAxisOrientation', invaxis)
        set.setValue(wms_conf_path + 'referer', ref)
        set.setValue(wms_conf_path + 'smoothPixmapTransform', smooth)
        set.setValue(wms_conf_path + 'url', url)
```

Since JPEG *and* PNG are available in both examples and the default values differ, the following question arises:

Q: How does QGIS determine the default image encoding and (if at all) how am I able to force QGIS to select PNG as default *if available*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think QGIS default format is the first `getMap` format from service. I have same problem, the default of QGIS was TIFF... I change the order of the `getMap` format in my MapServer service. I put PNG first before TIF and now the default in QGIS is PNG. Now PNG is first format `getMap` from service and is default in QGIS.

Service capabilities, PNG first:

[image: serviceCapabilities]